# Unable to retrieve test iteration object - Azure Devops Test Management

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests

I am trying to automate testing for my project. I created test plans, test suites and test cases. My test case has multiple steps with parameters. I would like to programmatically read through test case steps and update each step with outcome.

1. Test Case Details: My test case has 2 steps with parameters and I have give 4 iterations of test data
   [Test Case work item with steps and parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDgIK.png)
2. Create Test Run: [Create Test Run API](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.1)
   [Create Test Run Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INQCJ.png)
3. Create Test Result: [Create Test Result API](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/test/Runs/%7BrunId%7D/results?api-version=5.1)
   [Create Test Result Request and Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS8ll.png)
4. Get Iterations: [Get Iterations API](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/test/Runs/%7BrunId%7D/Results/%7BtestCaseResultId%7D/iterations/%7BiterationId%7D?includeActionResults=%7BincludeActionResults%7D&api-version=5.1) I am getting 0 iterations here when I expect 4 iteration as per no of parameters provided
   [Get Iterations Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQhIn.png)

I am not sure why I am getting 0 iterations. I could n't find api to add iterations and also whatever iteration details I mentioned in request object of step3, api is not picking up. Can you suggest me on

A) How to get iterations list

B) What do I need mention for action path is action results of Iteration results object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Through [Iterations - List rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/iterations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) api ,you can get the iterations for a result.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/iterations?api-version=5.1
```

[image]

Interations are not displayed in the response of `get test result` rest api. To get the iterstions list, you need to use the dedicated `iterstions-list` api .

If `Iterations-List` rest api does not return any iterations, you need to check if your test result is linked with iterations in the test result page.

[image]

In addition, this needs to be based on manual testing, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-manual-tests?view=azure-devops) for details.